# Facebook SDK - Posting a Dialog Resets the Default Value

Tags: android, facebook, game-maker

Scenario:

- Set the following values
  "link" = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.company.myapp"
  "name" = "MyApp by MyName"
  "caption" = "www.mywebsite.com"
  "description" = "Scored 9999 in MyGame"
- Trigger a "feed" dialog to allow the user to post
- When the dialog shows, it has the preview of the game. The Title says "MyApp by MyName". The Description says "Scored 9999 in MyGame"
- When I posted the status and checked my wall about the status, It has the previous of the game linked to Google Play Store but the Title is the original title of the game and the Description says "Apps for Pages" which I think is the default?

I'm pretty sure there's nothing mentioned in the Facebook SDK documentation that the developers aren't allowed to somewhat "modify" the link preview.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Did I miss something?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android:

> Note: If your app share links to the iTunes or Google Play stores, we do not post any images or descriptions that you specify in the share. Instead we post some app information we scrape from the app store directly with the Webcrawler. This may not include images. To preview a link share to iTunes or Google Play, enter your URL into the [Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/).

Obviously a scam prevention measure of sorts.

Comment: I had both my hands face palming. Thanks @CBroe.